# Installing rgeos Redhat

Tags: r, linux, redhat

I am using RStudio and Redhat:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago).
```

When trying to use the install rgeos in R, I got the following error message:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package rgeos had non-zero exit status
```

After some Googling, I found the following code to install geos:

```
cd /path/to/src/geos/ 
wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.6.1.tar.bz2
tar -vxjf geos-3.6.1.tar.bz2 
cd geos-3.6.1 
./configure --prefix=/path/to/install/geos 
make 
make check 
make install
```

However, I am on a shared university system and so get the following error:

```
/bin/mkdir -p '/path/to/install/geos/include/geos/algorithm/locate'
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory `/path': Permission denied
```

I am new to Linux, so I am not sure if there is an easy fix to this problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you really using _"/path/to/install"_ or a path of your own ? With which user are you connected on that server ( `id` to see it ) ?

Comment: I did try /path/to/install.  Once I read your question, I tried my own path.  This meant I successfully downloaded geos.  But, I still get the same error in R: Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package rgeos had non-zero exit status